# Extracting Text From an Excel Substring

Tags: excel

I'm trying to extract the country, state and city part of a text string and put the info into separate columns each in Excel.
I've tried using XLOOKUP and a separate list with every country's name, however, it didn't work... Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Text to columns?

Comment: I've tried, but the information is not always in the same position (e.g. the country name is sometimes after the second, sometimes after the fourth comma and sometimes at the end).

Comment: That's why you have the xlookup?

Comment: exactly. I've added another screenshot. Not sure if I'm using the function correctly since the desired substring (eg. "Italy") is not separate...

Comment: You didn't do text to columns.

Comment: well I did but this results in quite a mess (screenshot). Or would you suggest using XLOOKUP after text to columns?

Comment: @clannishduke Sorry for the other user I flagged his comment. You may want to look for a VBA solution depending on the complexity. Perhaps a list of countries to look for and then `MID` the string based on its location. You can text to column on commas if that gets you close enough for manual cleanup.